# No se muestra una segunda tabla en la consola de h2

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, h2

Esoty haciendo un proyecto en SpringBoot utilizando la base de datos que trae de H2. Realmente mis conocimientos son muy bajos en este tema.

La cosa es la siguiente, despues de muchos tutoriales logré crear una tabla "Usuarios" con unos datos precargados, pero quiero crear otra tabla totalmente aparte que se llama "SesionActual". Sin embargo solo logro que se muestre en consola la tabla de "Usuarios", la otra ni se crea.

Archivo: User.java

```
package los.habilidosisimos.habil2.model;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;


import jakarta.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;


@Entity
@Table(name = "Usuarios")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public class User implements Serializable {

    public User( String nombre, String apellido, String correo, String password){
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.apellido = apellido;
        this.correo = correo;
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String nombre;
    private String apellido;
    private String correo;
    private String password;


}
```

Esto funciona bien, y además tiene otra tabla agregada a este.

El repositorio es el siguiente

Archivo: UserRepository.java

```
package los.habilidosisimos.habil2.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;


import los.habilidosisimos.habil2.model.User;


public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    User findByNombre(String nombre);
}
```

Y mediante el archivo que ejecuta se precargan algunos datos

```
package los.habilidosisimos.habil2;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;


import los.habilidosisimos.habil2.model.User;

import los.habilidosisimos.habil2.repository.UserRepository;


@SpringBootApplication
public class Habil2Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        ConfigurableApplicationContext configurableApplicationContext = SpringApplication.run(Habil2Application.class, args);

        //SpringApplication.run(Habil2Application.class, args);

        UserRepository userRepository = configurableApplicationContext.getBean(UserRepository.class);
        User user = new User("Gustavo", "Cabrera", "aaa@gmail.com", "password");
        userRepository.save(user);
}}
```

Aqui creo la tabla de "SesionActual"

Archivo:CurrentSession.java

```
package los.habilidosisimos.habil2.model;

import java.io.Serializable;

import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

@Entity
@Table(name = "Sesion_Actual")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class CurrentSession implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String currentUser;
    private boolean session;

    public CurrentSession(String currentUser, boolean session) {
        this.currentUser = currentUser;
        this.session = session;
    }
}
```

y su repositorio, que no se si es necesario

Archivo: CurrentSessionRepository.java

```
package los.habilidosisimos.habil2.repository;

import los.habilidosisimos.habil2.model.CurrentSession;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface CurrentSessionRepository extends JpaRepository<CurrentSession, Long> {
}
```

E igualmente en la consola se muestra "Usuarios" y no "SesionActual", pero se ve reflejado en el apartado de sequences... He intetntado de todo y no logro nada.

de verdad agradezco si alguien sabe o puede ayudarme, ademas de darme consejos para mejorar.

gracias!
[image: Consola de H2]